# Class component: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a class component User and I would like to render what is in the `state.user`.
With Redux Dev Tools I can see that user has correct values.

This is what I have so far:

```
class User extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUser('60ab0b564fbb1d334002c777');
    }

    renderUser = (user) => {
        return (
            user !== {} ? <p>{user.name}</p> : 'User not found'
        )
    }

    render() {
        console.log('props', this.props);
        return (
                <div>
                    {this.renderUser(this.props.users.user)}
                </div>

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getUser,
})(User);
```

When I log `this.props` under render method, it logs:

```
getUser: ƒ ()
user: undefined
```

In my store where I combine reducers, I have:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    users: userReducer
});
```

That's why I need to do `this.props.users.user` to get to the user.
User's initial state is `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did it wrong at mapStateToProps.

Do this there

```
user: state.users
```

Then in the render method

```
this.props.user.user
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand how that mapStateToProps works.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state should be

User's initial state is `{name: ''}` not `{}`. Cause when the component 1st rendering your function need to access the `user.name`

Also you have typo here

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.users,
})
```

Comment: not necessarily. He maybe setting the initial state as empty object and then replacing it with another object with key name